# Как лучше всего передать русский текст по ссылке

Tags: php, get, экранирование

Из прошлого вопроса у меня хорошо получилось отправить и принять кавычки через функцию htmlspecialchars (прописал там где отправлял в ссылке и там где принимал в форме).

Теперь вторая проблема - как лучше всего передать русский текст по ссылке и потом принять его через $_Get[''] ?

htmlentities или url encode или вообще неправильным путем я пошел?

Пробовал htmlentities( XXXXXXXX, "UTF-8") там где отправляю и там где принимаю. В итоге пустое место - нет текста. Не смог отследить - еще на стадии отправления уже ничего не передается или расшифровывает и ничего нет.

Comment: Читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php Там и примеры приведены.

Comment: да, спасибо, кажется понял, надо в паре использовать. сейчас попробую.. encode и htmlentities

Comment: просто urlencode в ссылке отправлении и ничего больше. супер. спс.

Answer (score 1):

просто urlencode($XXX) и ничего больше а на принимающей стороне просто $_GET['XXX']